# Stop a function when the last page is reached with Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, loops, tampermonkey

1. I am running a userscript with Tampermonkey that loops through the pages and load them using this code:

   nextPage();

   ```
       function nextPage() {
                    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
               document.getElementsByClassName('paginate_button')[i].click();
                          }
       }
   ```
2. I just hardcoded in page number 5 but I want the script to stop running when the last page is reached. 
   If you click on the NEXT button on the final page, the page refreshes but stays on the current page. It does not opens up a new page.
3. The html surrounding the Next button looks like this:

   `<a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="AllInventoryList" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" id="AllInventoryList_next">Next</a>`

Comment: How do you find out how many pages are there? Does the page itself say somewhere, even within markup? If not, can you find out which page are you currently on and if clicking "next" leaves that unchanged? Do you have a sample of the HTML? Particularly where the pagination is - if you can see something like `page 1/3` or anything to that effect?

Comment: I know that there are 36 pages but we keep adding items to the list, so the page number can grow without me paying attention to it.

Here is a sample of the HTML of the last three buttons:
```<a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="AllInventoryList" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0">35</a>
<a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="AllInventoryList" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0">36</a></span>
<a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="AllInventoryList" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" id="AllInventoryList_next">Next</a></div>```

Maybe something with class="paginate_button next"??